# Display correct parameter label in validation rules

Tags: laravel, validation

I have trouble displaying the correct validation parameter label in my Laravel form. Please see attached image for further explanation. How can I get the label to display `"The End Date must be a date after Start Date."`? I feel I have tried everything.
In the resources/lang/en/validation.php I would like the `:date` parameter to display correctly, so in this example "Start Date".

```
'after' => 'The :attribute must be a date after :date.',
```

[image]

Comment: Provide your `after` validation rule with the name of the field you want to compare it against [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-after).

Comment: Thanks! I have that already though. That is what is currently showing up in the red text. "group.0.start".